# wxWidgets: Preferred way to name .po/.mo files: en/app.mo or en.mo?

Tags: internationalization, wxwidgets, gettext

My application is to be written using wxWidgets, but the question may be related to using `gettext` in general.

For the application named `app`, some sources suggest I sould create `<lang>/` subdirectory, create the `app.po` file inside with the translation, and convert it to the distributed `app.mo` file in the subdir.

Another approach is to create `app.pot` (i.e. the template from the sources via `xgettext`), and to `msginit` and `msgmerge` it to the `<lang>.po` for the language.

For the first approach, more `.mo` files can be put inside the `<lang>/` subdirectory. Also the `wxLocale::AddCatalog()` gets the *domain* name (where the domain can naturally be `app`, `wxstd`, etc.). On the other hand, the `<lang>.po` file name is descriptive on itself -- wherever it is located.

What are the pros and cons of the two approaches? Is there any text that explains the path to be chosen?

Thanks for your time and experience,

Petr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Unix convention is to use `app.mo` for binary catalogs, see the contents of `/usr/share/locale` directory. Sometimes `lang.po` is however used for the source ones, as done in wxWidgets itself (see its `locale` subdirectory), but they're still installed into language-specific subdirectory using the app-dependent name.

Comment: Does it mean that the `lang.po` is always converted to `app.mo` in such case? (I am not using Unix for more than 10 years.)

Comment: What do you mean by "converted"? It's not done automatically, it's up to you to run `msgfmt` with the correct arguments.

Comment: Yes. I understand it is not done automatically. (Sorry for my English. It is my fourth language.) Is the recommended way to keep my sources in say `cs/cs.po` and then to generate `cs/app.mo` for the distribution?

Comment: I don't think there is really a recommended way per se but it doesn't make much sense to use `cs/cs.po`, the only 2 cases I've ever seen were to use `lang.po` and put all the files in the same directory (which can be called `intl`, `gettext`, `locale` or something else) or put `app.po` files in subdirectories. But, again, this is just a de facto observation, I'm not aware of any standard about this.